# Crystal Reports - database connection conflict

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a web application that uses crystal reports.

I currently have a connection to an oracle database using odp.NET and everything works fine, when I implement these crystal reports using drag and drop tools via the designer page in visual studio, the previous database connection is not working anymore, and fails to import any existing data which it was importing. Having said that the Crystal Reports now work.

What could i do to prevent this? does it have anything to do with the source of the report overwriting the previous connection?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, 
it was to remove the login which is displayed before showing the report, seems like that was the conflict